# How to add a loop into macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I need to add a second loop into my code. Currently it prints by going through a list (in sheet named "Dealer" and starting at "B2" and prints a different PDF for each item on the list.

The second loop i need would have to be a long the same lines. It must go through a list of languages, in a seperate worksheet, and reprint each PDF that has multiple lagnuages.

Any help with this would be much appreciated. My code is as follows....

```
Dim PathString As String

Sub Print_************_2_ImpactValidationReport()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Dealer").Select
Range("B2").Select


    While Not ActiveCell.Value = Empty

    Sheets("ImpactValidationReport").Range("AO1").Value = ActiveCell.Value
    Sheets("ImpactValidationReport").Select
    'Call ChangeGraphAxis
    Range("A4").Select
    Sheets("ImpactValidationReport").Select
    Application.StatusBar = "Executing - Please be patient..."
    Call Print_To_File4(Sheets("ImpactValidationReport").Range("AO1").Value)
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Sheets("Dealer").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Wend

Sheets("ImpactValidationReport").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("ImpactValidationReport").Select
Range("A3").Select

MsgBox "All Completed, Please check Files!"

End Sub


Function Print_To_File4(Dealer As String)

'PathString = ***************************\Reporting\DistrictReports\2_ImpactValidationReport" & DealerGroup & ".pdf"
'ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PathString

CurrentDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    CurrentDir & "\Reporting\DistrictReports\2_ImpactValidationReport\District_Action_Report_" & Dealer & "_2_ImpactValidationReport_" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy") _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want the following structure (I use `i` and `j` as increments to control the loops):

```
i = 1
While Not cells(i,1) = Empty
    'check all items
    j=1
    while not sheets("language").cells(j,1) = Empty
        'check all languages for the item
        j=j+1
    wend

    i=i+1
wend
```